# Error code 2753 during install

Tags: windows-installer, pex

Today I needed to re-install Microsoft Pex on my develop machine.

I'm using Windows 7, 32 bit, Visual Studio 2010, .NET 2/3.5

I launched the usual installer, but it stopped with a mysterious 2753 error.

How can I proceed with the installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is:

- From the command line launch "regsvr32 vbscript.dll".
- After a few moments the message "DllRegisterServer in vbscript.dll succeeded." will appear

I hope this could be a solution for other people.

Comment: Nearly 10 years later and people still don't get it. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2004/05/20/136530.aspx

Comment: You're right @ChristopherPainter and I think there's still little common knowledge about installation best practices.

Comment: perhaps it only works with microsoft pex, I have the same problem, but a different software generates the 2753 error, and "regsvr32 vbscript.dll" does not work.

Comment: @Fresco did you find another solution?

Comment: @alcor Nope, instead I just extracted the file using `msiexec /a C:\source.msi /qb TARGETDIR=C:\dest`

Comment: @Christopher Painter Another 4 years and scripting (javascript, python, etc) is now mainstream not only on client side but on server side too (e.g. node.js).

Comment: ActiveScript VBScript/JScript and NodeJS JavaScript aren't even remotely similiar technologies.  The only thing in common is the word script.

Answer (score 2):

When updating "Microsoft Azure Information Protection" with the "Software Center", I had this error as detailed below:

> The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this
> package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code
> is 2753. The arguments are: adxregistrator.exe

More precisely, the error was:

> Error 2753:  The File 'adxregistrator.exe' is not marked for
> installation.

To investigate this error, [I downloaded Microsoft troubleshooting tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed).

This allowed me to detect two instances of "Microsoft Azure Information Protection". I troubleshooted and uninstalled both.

After rebooting my PC, the application update succeeded with the Software Center.

Answer (score 1):

Verify if OS version is compatible with SDK version.

Trying to install Windows SDK **8**, I had the same error code. The problem occurred because my OS version is **8.1**.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for error 2753 is fairly explicit:

"The File '[2]' is not marked for installation."

And typically you get it when you try to run a custom action based on a executable file that you're not installing or is absent for some other reason. If the file is in a feature or component that is not being installed and you call it as a CA you get this error. If the version of the file on disk is higher than yours in the MSI then yours won't be installed so you'll get this error because the exe you explicitly wanted to run as a CA didn't get installed.

Comment: _If the version of the file on disk is higher than yours in the MSI then yours won't be installed_ was the essential hint for me - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar 2753 error when trying to install [Windows SDK for Windows 8](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-sdk) on Windows 10.

Then I see from the above link this:

> Supported operating systems
>
> Windows 8, Windows 7, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2

So I decided ***not to hack around*** and use [Windows SDK for Window 10](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

The error is gone.